# Passing JMeter user defined variables as parameters in GitHub workflow

Tags: github, jmeter, azure-load-testing

In JMeter, parameterised the URL and declared it in UDV as below.
[image]
Replaced the HTTP requests as ${URL}
Want to run this test in Azure Load test resource using github workflows.Declared the URL as inputs and in the env as below.
[image]
[image]

Also tried sending value as ${{ github.event.inputs.URL}}. But it didn't work.
When workflow is triggered, the URL value is passed as empty. How to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

From JMeter perspective the way of accessing an environment variable value is correct apart from the small improvement: you should use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy).

[image]

or alternatively there is [__env() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#envsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) which can be installed as a part of **Custom JMeter Functions** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

From [Github Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) perspective you can access the value as `${{ github.event.inputs.URL }}` where required